# Validating boolean variable in powershell task in Azure DevOps yaml pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am writing a basic powershell task, in a task template, that does something rather simple. Reads a variable (for testing purposes set to True) and evaluates it in an if/else statement. The variable `candeploy` is set in a variable template, other than the template where the task is defined.

```
    - powershell:  |
        if($(candeploy) -eq $true) {
          write-host This should run when true - $(candeploy)
        } else {
          write-host This should run when false - $(candeploy)
        }
      displayName: Verify Start Parameters
      #condition: eq( variables.candeploy, true )
      failOnStderr: true
      errorActionPreference: stop
```

Though `$(candeploy)` is always true the if statement always results to `false`.

I tried it with `if($(candeploy)) {` or `if(${{ $(variables.candeploy) }} -eq $true) {`, but result is always the same.

[Result of running task.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTYWP.png)

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check the answer below, which should be able to correct the script? You may consider accepting it. That may help other community members with similar concerns. Thx.

Comment: Hi @HeraldGjura, May I know if the answers below can resolve your query? If the suggestion helps, you may consider [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it very interesting that both [environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables) and single/double quoted [macro syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#macro-syntax-variables) worked.

```
variables:
- name: candeploy
  value: True
steps:
- powershell: |
    if( $env:CANDEPLOY -eq $true) {
      write-host This should run when true - $(candeploy)
    } else {
      write-host This should run when false - $(candeploy)
    }
  displayName: Verify Start Parameters - Env Var
  failOnStderr: true
  errorActionPreference: stop

- powershell:  |
    if( '$(CANDEPLOY)' -eq $true) {
      write-host This should run when true - $(candeploy)
    } else {
      write-host This should run when false - $(candeploy)
    }
  displayName: Verify Start Parameters - Single Quoted Macro Syntax
  failOnStderr: true
  errorActionPreference: stop

- powershell:  |
    if( "$(CANDEPLOY)" -eq $true) {
      write-host This should run when true - $(candeploy)
    } else {
      write-host This should run when false - $(candeploy)
    }
  displayName: Verify Start Parameters - Double Quoted Macro Syntax
  failOnStderr: true
  errorActionPreference: stop
```

[image]

I think this is because variables with macro syntax get processed **before** a task executes during runtime. When the system encounters a macro expression, it **replaces** the expression with the contents of the variable.

Here are the differences in the script from the debug logs.
[image]

Hope the suggestion would work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not set variable with the type of **bool**, variable should be only **string** type in azure devop yaml. ["All variables are strings and are mutable. The value of a variable can change from run to run or job to job of your pipeline."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)

below is my sample code for testing (with variable type string not boolean), hope this can help.

> Note: be caution of the variable only pass the pure string, not with
> quotes.

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
  candeploy: 'true'

steps:
- powershell: |
    write-host "test 1 candeploy is: $(candeploy)"

    if($(candeploy) -eq 'true') {
      write-host This should run when true - $(candeploy)
    } else {
      write-host This should run when false - not $(candeploy)
    }
  displayName: Verify variables 1

- powershell: |
    write-host "test 1 candeploy is: $(candeploy)"

    if('$(candeploy)' -eq 'true') {
      write-host This should run when true - $(candeploy)
    } else {
      write-host This should run when false - not $(candeploy)
    }
  displayName: Verify variables 2
```

result:

[image]

[image]